# Sending Email asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, email

Im having a problem using Email.SendMail(). I need to add more details like Event_Location, Event_Start, etc to the "Email Msg" from the Events table in the database but the var item is already called by events. I would like to know if there is a way to put two var i.e events and members either in the foreach loop or another method?

```
public void Send()
{
   var events = from a in db.Members.ToList()
                join e in db.Events.ToList() on a.Hobby_Code equals e.Hobby_Code
                where a.Postal_Code == e.Postal_Code || e.Event_Status ==("A")

   var member= from w in db.Members.TOList()
               join z in db.Events.ToList() on w.Event_ID equals z.Event_ID
               select w

   foreach (var item in events)
      Email.SendMail(item.Member_Email_Address,"Subject","Email Msg",false);
}
```

Model Class  for Member

```
  public class Member
  {
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Member_ID { get; set; }



    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Section Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("Section Name")]
    public string Postal_Code { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An email address is required")]
    [DisplayName("Email Address")]
    public string Member_Email_Address { get; set; }



    [DisplayName("Hobby Code")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Hobby is required")]
    public string Hobby_Code { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Event ID")]
    public int? Event_ID { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return Member_Last_Name + " " + Member_First_Name;
        }
    }


    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

}
```

Model Class for Event

```
     public class Event 
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key]
    public int Event_ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Event Location is required")]
    [DisplayName("Event Location")]
    public string Postal_Code { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Event Status")]
    public string Event_Status { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Event Start Date")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime Event_Start { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Event End Date")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime Event_End { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Event Type")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Event Type is required")]
    public string Hobby_Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [DisplayName(" Event Description")]
    public string Event_Description { get; set; }
```

Comment: What do the Member and Event model classes look like?

Comment: Is Event_ID in Member a foreign key reference to Event_ID in Event?  In other words, does every member have one event?

Comment: Yes Members are invited to one event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an anonymous method to return only those properties you want, i.e.:

```
var events = from a in db.Members.ToList()
                join e in db.Events.ToList() on a.Hobby_Code equals e.Hobby_Code             
                where a.Postal_Code == e.Postal_Code || e.Event_Status ==("A")
                select new { email = a.Member_Email_Address, location = e.Event_Location, eventStart = e.Event_Start};
```

and then access it in the for loop like so:

```
foreach (var item in events)      
    Email.SendMail(item.email,"Subject",String.Format("Location: {0}",item.location),false); // including all the other variables required and excluding the formatting
```

Comment: Thanks it works just having a problem with the readibility of the Subject string , its all joined , i need it to be seperate?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain a bit more, maybe an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ASP .NET MVC's automatic entity mapping properly, it will do all the joins for you.  In Member you should have a reference to `Event event` rather than `Event_ID`.  Then you can simply do:

```
foreach (var member in db.Members)
{
   String msgBody = "You are invited to " && member.event.Event_Description && " on " && member.event.Event_Start;

   Email.SendMail(member.Member_Email_Address,"Subject", msgBody, false);
}
```